# How to add two words in a javascript function without using any library?

Tags: javascript

How can 2 objects be added through a js function without using 'join' that the result output below is true? This is the code that I have now:

```
 var twoObjs = function(obj1, obj2) {
 return obj1 + obj2; // does not work
};

twoObjs("dog", "ball");

var output = mergeObjs({dog: "Max"}, {toy: "mouse"});

console.log(output.cat === "Max")
console.log(output.toy === "mouse")
```

Comment: so you merge the objects like your function call says. Did you search how to merge objects?

Comment: Not sure why you have the `//does not work` comment in your first function. [It works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/5padydvL/).

Comment: @Santi, it will work for strings, but not for objects.

Comment: @Dekel I realize that. OP was using it with strings though. I believe I'm just not understanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.assign` to create a new object

```js
var mergeObjs = function(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.assign({},obj1,obj2);
};

var output = mergeObjs({
    dog: "Max"
}, {
    toy: "mouse"
});

console.log(output.dog)
console.log(output.toy)
```

Comment: Not widely supported.. another option is..  https://jsfiddle.net/323vbaub/

Comment: Agreed with @Pamblam